# Super methods in service

Tags: android, methods, service, super

I want Override a method in Service that will show me a Toast whenever :

- back button,home button, power button was clicked or whenever activity or view or windows was changed.

I want something in service that will react on that kind of things. I cant Override super methods like onBackButttonPressed in service so i need something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can neither override any methods in `Service` nor do something else to detect these events outside of your own app.